# Sharepoint list - only allow two with the same Schedule date or throw validation msg

Tags: list, validation, sharepoint

I am working on Sharepoint office 365 version. I have made a custom list, which is my schedule list. I am using share-point default form functionality to add rows in it. It has a schedule-date field. I want only two rows to be input for that particular date and if user add the third one on the same date, it should say, you are only allowed to add two records on the same day(date). Basically, hack into the validation and shows that message. Is there a simple way to do it, please if someone can guide.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For classic view, you could use `PreSaveAction` for client side validation.

Below is sample script to check items count, you need update the camlquery per your requirement.

```
function PreSaveAction() {
        var check = false;
        getListItemCount(function (error, items) {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
                alert('Check data failed');
            }
            else {
                var length = items.$2_1.length;
                if (length < 5) {
                    check = true;
                } else {
                    alert('over max items');
                }
            }
        });
        return check;
    }
    var getListItemCount = function (callback) {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var listid = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId;
        var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById(listid);
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        var items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(items);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            callback(null, items);
        }, function (a, b) {
            callback(new Error(b.get_message()));
        });
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this one.